# Variadic content leads to AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address

Tags: c++, c++11, heap-memory, address-sanitizer

Object of type `AAAA` can hold any other object depending on its category. For example it holds object of type `BBBB`. An object of type `BBBB` also can hold any object content depending on its category.

Address sanitizer fails for the following code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class AAAA;
AAAA generate_a();

enum class A_CATEGORY
{
    Not_Seclected,
    B_DATA_CAT,
    // other categories
};

enum class B_CATEGORY
{
    Not_Seclected,
    C_DATA_CAT,
    // other categories
};

class CCCC
{
public:
    vector<int> needed_dummy;
};

class BBBB
{
public:
    B_CATEGORY category = B_CATEGORY::Not_Seclected;
    void * p_variadic_content = nullptr;

    BBBB()
    {
        cout<<"BBBB: default constructor"<<endl;
    }

    BBBB(const BBBB &obj)
    {
        cout<<"BBBB: copy constructor {"<<endl;
        *this = obj;
        if(obj.p_variadic_content != nullptr)
        {
            switch(this->category)
            {
                case B_CATEGORY::C_DATA_CAT:
                    this->p_variadic_content = (void *) new CCCC();
                    *((CCCC*) this->p_variadic_content) = *((CCCC*) obj.p_variadic_content);
                    break;
                default:
                    cout<<"Unknown category"<<endl;
            }
        }
        cout<<"BBBB: copy constructor }"<<endl;
    }

    ~BBBB()
    {
        switch(this->category)
        {
            case B_CATEGORY::C_DATA_CAT:
                assert(p_variadic_content != nullptr);
                delete (CCCC *) p_variadic_content;
                p_variadic_content = nullptr;
                cout<<"~BBBB"<<endl;
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"Unknown category"<<endl;
        }
    }
};

class AAAA
{
public:
    A_CATEGORY category = A_CATEGORY::Not_Seclected;
    void * p_variadic_content = nullptr;

    AAAA()
    {
       cout<<"AAAA: default constructor"<<endl;
    }

    AAAA(const AAAA &obj)
    {
        cout<<"AAAA: copy constructor {"<<endl;
        *this = obj;
        if(obj.p_variadic_content != nullptr)
        {
            switch(this->category)
            {
                case A_CATEGORY::B_DATA_CAT:
                    this->p_variadic_content = (void *) new BBBB();
                    *((BBBB*) this->p_variadic_content) = *((BBBB*) obj.p_variadic_content);
                    break;
                default:
                    cout<<"Unknown category"<<endl;
            }
        }
        cout<<"AAAA: copy constructor }"<<endl;
    }

    ~AAAA()
    {
        switch(this->category)
        {
            case A_CATEGORY::B_DATA_CAT:
                assert(p_variadic_content != nullptr);
                delete (BBBB *) p_variadic_content;
                p_variadic_content = nullptr;
                cout<<"~AAAA"<<endl;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Unknown category" << endl;
        }
    }
};

AAAA generate_a()
{
    AAAA a_object;
    a_object.category = A_CATEGORY::B_DATA_CAT;
    BBBB * b_object = new BBBB();
    CCCC * c_object = new CCCC();
    b_object->category = B_CATEGORY::C_DATA_CAT;
    b_object->p_variadic_content = (void *) c_object;
    a_object.p_variadic_content = (void *) b_object;
    return a_object;
}

int main()
{
    vector<AAAA> aaa;
    AAAA a_object = generate_a();
    aaa.push_back(std::move(a_object));

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled by

```
g++ -std=c++11 -fsanitize=address  aaaa.cpp  && ./a.out
```

The execution fails with the following trace

```
AAAA: default constructor
BBBB: default constructor
AAAA: copy constructor {
BBBB: default constructor
AAAA: copy constructor }
~BBBB
~AAAA
=================================================================
==17317==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x60300000efe8 at pc 0x000000401d30 bp 0x7ffd036102a0 sp 0x7ffd03610290
READ of size 8 at 0x60300000efe8 thread T0
    #0 0x401d2f in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::~vector() (/media/common/tmp/cpp/Untitled Folder/aaaa/a.out+0x401d2f)
    #1 0x401701 in CCCC::~CCCC() (/media/common/tmp/cpp/Untitled Folder/aaaa/a.out+0x401701)
    #2 0x4017da in BBBB::~BBBB() (/media/common/tmp/cpp/Untitled Folder/aaaa/a.out+0x4017da)
    #3 0x401c4a in AAAA::~AAAA() (/media/common/tmp/cpp/Untitled Folder/aaaa/a.out+0x401c4a)
    #4 0x402b56 in void std::_Destroy<AAAA>(AAAA*) (/media/common/tmp/cpp/Untitled Folder/aaaa/a.out+0x402b56)
    #5 0x402846 in void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<AAAA*>(AAAA*, AAAA*) (/media/common/tmp/cpp/Untitled Folder/aaaa/a.out+0x402846)
    #6 0x4023ff in void std::_Destroy<AAAA*>(AAAA*, AAAA*) (/media/common/tmp/cpp/Untitled Folder/aaaa/a.out+0x4023ff)
    #7 0x402098 in void std::_Destroy<AAAA*, AAAA>(AAAA*, AAAA*, std::allocator<AAAA>&) (/media/common/tmp/cpp/Untitled Folder/aaaa/a.out+0x402098)
    #8 0x401e17 in std::vector<AAAA, std::allocator<AAAA> >::~vector() (/media/common/tmp/cpp/Untitled Folder/aaaa/a.out+0x401e17)
    #9 0x4014d4 in main (/media/common/tmp/cpp/Untitled Folder/aaaa/a.out+0x4014d4)
    #10 0x7f2bbb9eb83f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2083f)
    #11 0x401118 in _start (/media/common/tmp/cpp/Untitled Folder/aaaa/a.out+0x401118)

0x60300000efe8 is located 8 bytes inside of 24-byte region [0x60300000efe0,0x60300000eff8)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f2bbc429b8a in operator delete(void*) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.2+0x99b8a)
    #1 0x4017e2 in BBBB::~BBBB() (/media/common/tmp/cpp/Untitled Folder/aaaa/a.out+0x4017e2)
    #2 0x401c4a in AAAA::~AAAA() (/media/common/tmp/cpp/Untitled Folder/aaaa/a.out+0x401c4a)
    #3 0x4014c8 in main (/media/common/tmp/cpp/Untitled Folder/aaaa/a.out+0x4014c8)
    #4 0x7f2bbb9eb83f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2083f)

previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f2bbc429592 in operator new(unsigned long) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.2+0x99592)
    #1 0x40126b in generate_a() (/media/common/tmp/cpp/Untitled Folder/aaaa/a.out+0x40126b)
    #2 0x401498 in main (/media/common/tmp/cpp/Untitled Folder/aaaa/a.out+0x401498)
    #3 0x7f2bbb9eb83f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2083f)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free ??:0 std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::~vector()
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c067fff9da0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff9db0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff9dc0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff9dd0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff9de0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
=>0x0c067fff9df0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fd[fd]fd fa
  0x0c067fff9e00: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff9e10: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff9e20: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff9e30: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff9e40: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Heap right redzone:      fb
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack partial redzone:   f4
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
==17317==ABORTING
```

So,

1. What is wrong?
2. How should I fix it without changing the structure? I am after a solution by correcting the memory management rather than getting around the problem. I am mainly after a fix in constructors/destructor. Also, I fill extend the categories. So, I am not after removing them. I will not accept removing `void*` or try replacing it by an explicit type.

Comment: You're not following the rule of 5: you've only implemented 2 out of 5 "special" functions. Assuming you don't want move construction and assignment, you're still missing the copy assignment operator. Think about what happens to the data that was stored in an object `A A_one` when you do `A_one = A_two;`. You're leaking the old data that was managed by `A_one` in that case. If you properly implement the copy assignment operator, that should solve the issue. In that case you probably want to rework the copy constructor as well, since you invoke copy assignment inside it.

Comment: @Darhuuk, Thanks for your comment. Not sure if by leaking you mean `*this = obj;`. This will copy a pointer only.

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from this line:

```
*((BBBB*) this->p_variadic_content) = *((BBBB*) obj.p_variadic_content);
```

Because class `BBBB` does not define a copy assignment operator, the default one will be used which will result in both `this` and `obj` having identical `BBBB::p_variadic_content` pointers to the same memory block. Later, when the two objects are destroyed, you try to free up the same memory block twice which results in your heap-use-after-free problem.

The solution is to define the assignment operator (`BBBB &operator=(const BBBB &)`) for class `BBBB`, and make changes to the copy constructor to not make use of it the way you are. Since the assignment operator should perform the required deep copy, then the copy constructor (which calls the copy assignment) would not need to make this copy.

Incidentally, you can reduce the need for those type casts by storing the newly allocated pointer in a local variable with the correct type. For example,

```
            case B_CATEGORY::C_DATA_CAT:
            {
                CCCC *pc = new CCCC;
                p_variadic_content = pc;
                *pc = *((CCCC*) obj.p_variadic_content);
                break;
            }
```

It is then easier to see that this can be condensed down into

```
            case B_CATEGORY::C_DATA_CAT:
                p_variadic_content = new CCCC(*(CCCC*) obj.p_variadic_content);
                break;
```

which avoids the error you get in the original code (but without fixing the underlying cause of the error).